# Extracting a nested list of matrix format from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

`"This is a matrix [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[p,q,r]]. But these are not a matrix [[2,5,9],[5,2]] or [[5,8,[5,6]],[5]]."`

I want to extract the nested list from the string. I want a output like this 
`[['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['p','q','r']]` and I do not want the other nested lists.

The nested list is not the specific one as above i.e. 3x3. It could be of any format like mxn. How can I extract this kind of nested list from a string using python and make it non-string so that I can use it?

Comment: You want the output as two dimensional list or as a string?

Comment: two dimensional list @thiruvenkadam

Comment: And another query. Will it be only two dimensional or could it be single or three dimensional as well?

Comment: only two dimensional

Comment: Since I could not add the answer, I will give you the logic here. (1) Use this expression to get the 2D lists as strings: re.findall(r"[^[]*\[([a-zA-Z0-9,\]\[]*)\]", my_string). (2) prepend the strings with [ and append a ]. (3) Use ast.literal_eval to convert the string list to list of lists. (4) For each and every element, check whether all inner lists have equal number of items and number of lists equals to number of items

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the rules that form your string. If it only has brackets around the list, it is safe to do:

```
s = "This is a matrix [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]."
matrix_s = re.search('\[.*\]', s).group()
matrix = ast.literal_eval(matrix_s)
```